# Chrome Developer Tools : I CSS Coverage unused bytes

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

I am trying to remove unused CSS from a webpage.

- In Chrome Developer Tools -> click on vertical three dots -> More tools -> Coverage.
- Click on any CSS
- We see a report wherein red indicates unused CSS, green indicates used CSS.

Is there a way to group CSS based off whether they are used or not? Right now, the red/green visual indicators are good, however, they don't provide an easy way to copy/paste just the used CSS.

[How to get CSS Code Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rH7F.png)

[Visual indicators for CSS code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC5ic.png)

Comment: I don't think so, that would actually be quite hard since what you see is the **live** version of the stylesheet. Which means that rearranging it would modify it, and thus possibly change the coverage of every rules. E.g if your stylesheet was made of `body{color:red} body{color: blue}`, the red one would be reported as unused, but if you sorted by unused last, then the blue one would become the unused one and your text would become red. But maybe there is a *freeze* option I'm unaware of...

Comment: (Previous comment is actually a bad example since it seems *coverage* doesn't detect overwritten rules as unused, but you get the idea)

Comment: This would be nice...

Answer (score 5):

DevTools technical writer here.

No, unfortunately there is no way to group, at the moment. We're aware that users want to be able to export used code to a file. Can't give a timeline on when that feature will ship, though.

Comment: Kayce - can you provide pointers on where this code/feature request ticket might possibly exist? I can try making a PR against it..

Comment: Hi @anurag here’s the [feature request](https://crbug.com/717195) and here’s the [code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/coverage/?q=Coverage+DevTools+&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs) I recommend leaving a message in the feature request ticket offering to work on the feature first before you start working on it, the engineer may have already started work on it.

Comment: Hi @KayceBasques - am I right in thinking that this can only work for a single page, it's not possible to record over a whole session like Firefox's Dust Me extension used to do?  Or is there a trick...? Thanks!

Comment: @Codemonkey you are right. It only works for a single page.

Comment: @KayceBasques is there an update if this feature is available or not?